# WordPress: New type of posts/pages in a custom display

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a page like `/news`, this page needs to have content similar to the top/bottom layout found in a simple WordPress theme:

```
Title "is a link also to access the post/page"
Space
Content of 160 Chars not more
```

to add new news simply, add new post or page and then simply make the new post like a normal post and choose an option there to make it in the news page.

This also should be in the RSS feed, but i think it will be as they are just customized posts/pages so no problem for that?

Comment: It seems like you want a custom post type but also a excerpt of 160 to only show 160 characters?

Comment: @DavidChase Thanks for your comment, it's not mandatory only 160 chars, i just wanted to point out that it will be short text, more or less 160 chars :)

Comment: Do you use posts anywhere else on your website? If not you could just use those? Otherwise use a custom post type like suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that will get you started, with just the basics

```
function custom_news() {
register_post_type(
            'news', 
            array(
                    'label' => __('News'),
                    'public' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'capability_type' => 'post',
                    'menu_position' => 100,
                    'menu_icon' => 'path/to/icon',
                    'supports' => array(
                                 'editor',
                                 'post-thumbnails',
                                 'excerpts',
                                 'custom-fields',
                                 'comments',
                                 'revisions')
            )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'articles', 'news', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => __('Articles') ) ); 

   } 
   add_action('init', 'custom_news');
```

and then use `WP_Query` to show the custom post where ever you want:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'news',
);


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
 echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($the_query->ID).'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
     echo '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
endwhile;


wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types). This should behave just like an ordinary post or page but with its own index page and backend management screens. You need to use [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to create the post type. After that things are mostly automatic. From the Codex, as a reference:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Books',
    'singular_name' => 'Book',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Book',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Book',
    'new_item' => 'New Book',
    'all_items' => 'All Books',
    'view_item' => 'View Book',
    'search_items' => 'Search Books',
    'not_found' =>  'No books found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No books found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Books'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

The parameters can be a bit confusing. [Smashing Magazine has a post that should help](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/).